# Unity UI TextBox Dynamic Height. How do I make it expand based on text amount?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

What up.

I'm instantiating a textbox gameobject.
Then filling it up with text.

Any way to make the textbox height dynamically change?

```
GameObject reply1 = Instantiate(replyText, transform.position, 
transform.rotation);
reply1.transform.SetParent(textArea.transform, false);
Text reply1text = reply1.GetComponent<Text>();
reply1text.text = gameRounds[roundCount].reply[0];
```

The width is fine, don't need to change it.

Answer (score 3):

You can add the **ContentSizeFitter** component to the text gameobject, and then set **Vertical Fit** to the *Prefered Size*. This solution only controls the text box's height.

If you want to control the parent's height automatically, follow those steps.

1. Add **Vertical Layout Group** to the Parent.

[image]

2. Add **Text** gameobject as a child and add a **Content Size Fitter** component.

[image]

3. Now try to change the text of the Text component in a script. You will notice that it doesn't work properly. You should manually update the parent's layout group.

```
{
     exampleText.text = "Text Example \n Test automatic height";
     Invoke("UpdateParentLayoutGroup", 0.1f);
}...

void UpdateParentLayoutGroup() {
     exampleText.gameObject.SetActive(false);
     exampleText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

4. Enjoy Unity !

Answer (score 2):

I need to correct @gmspacex's answer, which is utterly wrong (the screenshot speaks for itself, showing a warning), for future reference. The correct way of setting a Text element with a dynamic height or width is clearly described here:
[Make children of a Layout Group fit their respective sizes](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/HOWTO-UIFitContentSize.html)

To summarize you just need to:

1. Add a vertical layout group to the parent
2. Add a *ContentSizeFitter* component to the same object and set *Vertical Fit* to *Preferred Size*
3. Toggle **ON**: control child size width and height, child force expand width
4. Toggle **OFF**: child force expand height

No shenanigans with toggling the component on and off.
If you find some element being "squashed", just add a *LayoutElement* component and set the *Min Height* property appropriately.

[screenshot of the correct way of setting up the vertical layout group component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFjUO.jpg)

Comment: Thank you for adding this clarification. It helped me solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text box's **Vertical Overflow** settings to **Overflow**. It automatically increases the textboxes height based on text content.
[image]

Comment: This only overflows the text, letting it continue outside of its dimensions. It does not change the textbox height as the OP asked. This wouldn't work if you wanted to dynamically update the size to fit in an area, i.e. a scroll area that grows as more text is added.